# current_timestamp in date field

Tags: database

How can I add current_timestamp or now for date feild in drupal database schema.

```
        'created' => array(
            'description' => t('Timestamp when the fee schedule was added.'),
            'type' => 'int',
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'unsigned' => TRUE,
        ),
```

Comment: I had a search on user.module. Drupal is saving created like $array['created'] = time();

Answer (score 7):

You can specify a driver-specific column type for MySQL using the `mysql_type` attribute:

```
function MYMODULE_schema (){
  $schema['table_name'] = array(
    'fields' => array(
      'created' => array(
        'mysql_type' => 'timestamp',
        'not null' => TRUE
      )
    )
  );

  return $schema;
}
```

Then, on enabling your module, you can simply modify the column to add the default/on-update behaviour:

```
function MYMODULE_enable() {
  db_query('
    ALTER TABLE {table_name} 
    MODIFY created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
  );
}
```

I've just tested that on Drupal 7 and it works a treat.

**NOTE:** If you don't want the timestamp to update every time the record is updated then just remove the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` part of the query.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to MySQL, the feature you want to look into straight from the docs is [time stamps](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

This would probably update the db table created by schema to the field type you are looking for:

```
MODIFY COLUMN `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp;
```

Just stumbled on [this post](http://drupal.org/node/1466122) stating timestamp support should be in for Drupal 8, so I assume (and I coud be wrong) it probably is not supported out of the box for D7. Just change the type to TIMESTAMP in your array, and see what gives but I would not wager on this working through the D7 schema api.

**UPDATE:**

Actually, look in the post. The patch will add support to timestamp in D7.
Major kudos to [drupalshrek](http://drupal.org/user/620770) for sharing this with us.

Database schema, once patched would be as follow:

```
<?php
$schema['vchess_moves'] = array(
  'description' => 'Contains the list of moves for each game',
  'fields' => array(
    'timestamp' => array(
    'description' => 'Exact date and time of the move',
    'type' => 'timestamp',
    'not null' => TRUE,
?>
```

Go see the post above for the patch, I won't repost his stuff here, not sure if doing so would be proper.

Hope this helps, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for Drupal 8.6.x just incase if someone is looking as I was :)

```
'created' => [
  'mysql_type' => 'timestamp',
  'not null' => TRUE,
  'mysql_default' => CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 ],
```

this is equivalent to ...

```
`created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```